# Iterating over list of raw strings isn't displaying correctly in a plot title

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, plot, string-formatting

I have a series of labels for a range of subplots, each of which is a raw string:

```
labels = [r"\$beta$", r"\$alpha$", r"$\omega$"]
```

I want my plots to have the Greek letters displayed, but when I do:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3)
for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    axs[i].set_title(label)
```

The titles show $beta$, $alpha$, and $omega$ instead of the desired output. I could just use Greek letters for my labels directly, but I was wondering if there's a way to achieve this with raw string formatting. I also tried `axs[i].set_title(fr"{label}")` and `axs[i].set_title(r"%s"%label)` but without luck so far. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slash goes before the keyword:

```
labels = [r"$\beta$", r"$\alpha$", r"$\omega$"]
```

see [here](https://latexref.xyz/Math-symbols.html) for more info